# R-exam mchoice: Error in moodlePercent(frac) : Percentage not in list of moodle fractions

Tags: r-exams

I have an mchoice question in file `32_est_summary.Rmd` in this public [repo](https://github.com/nmolanog/r_exam_issue).
(I don't share the code here since it is a bit large and stack over flow policies don't allow me to publish the question with all the code)

The question renders without problem in html format using

```
exams2html("32_est_summary.Rmd",
           converter = "pandoc-mathjax")
```

However, there is an issue when trying to export it as XML. In file  `32_est_summary.Rmd` line 36, I have a variable which controls the number of random generated false answers (`nrep`). If `nrep`is equal to 2, then I get the following error message:

`Error in moodlePercent(frac) : Percentage not in list of moodle fractions`

Is this normal? Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Moodle only certain percentage values are available for scoring a given item, namely:

```
exams:::moodleFractions
##  [1] 100.00000  90.00000  83.33333  80.00000  75.00000  70.00000  66.66667
##  [8]  60.00000  50.00000  40.00000  33.33333  30.00000  25.00000  20.00000
## [15]  16.66667  14.28571  12.50000  11.11111  10.00000   5.00000
```

Your item has 28 answer alternatives and thus there is a good chance that a percentage is required for scoring that is not available in the list above. Thus, you either need to reduce the number of answer alternatives or switch to a different question format.

In your case I would recommend to switch the `extype` to `cloze` and split up the exercise into subitems. For example, you have something like:

```
* El estimador del cuantil 0.5 es 64.22
* El estimador del cuantil 0.5 es 14.4832
* El estimador del cuantil 0.5 es 209.7624
* El estimador del cuantil 0.5 es 52.3775
* El estimador de la mediana es 64.22
* El estimador de la mediana es 209.7624
* El estimador de la mediana es 52.3775
* El estimador de la mediana es 77.2675
```

Either you can switch it to `clozetype` as `schoice|schoice`, i.e., two single-choice answer list with one correct solution each. Or you can switch that to `clozetype` as `num|num` with

```
* El estimador del cuantil 0.5 es:
* El estimador de la mediana es:
```

Comment: ```extype: cloze``` is great. Thanks for point to that. Good examples of this can be found in http://www.r-exams.org/intro/dynamic/. I found very interesting the example of boxhist (http://www.r-exams.org/templates/boxhist/), for any one interested.

Comment: It's a useful information. IMHO should be included in `?exams2moodle`.

Comment: Good point, thanks! Added to the devel version on R-Forge now.